# how to get individual value from LinkedHashSet<Integer> having size(n,3)

Tags: java

`[[58, 89, -50], [58, 50, -89], [89, 50, -58], [-51, -35, 75], [-51, -75, 35], [-35, -75,` `51], [-83, -60, -97], [-83, 97, 60], [-60, 97, 83], [null]]`

in the example above `LinkedHashSet<Integer> [size<N><3>]` having N no. of Integer 
objects and each object contains 3 primitive int values. I want to access this 
in three different int type list so that i get

```
list1[1] : {58,58,89,-51,.......}
list2[1] : {89,50,50,-35,.......}
list3[1] : {-50,-89,-58,75.......}
```

As i do in C language let P pointing to first Node we access as

```
struct Node *P=Start;
int i=0;
while(P!=NULL){
int a[i]=P->data1;
int b[i]=P->data2;
int c[i]=P->data3;
i++;}
```

how it will be in Java.Please help me.Thanks!Ashish

Comment: Can you use a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>)`?

Comment: "... having N no. of Integer objects and each object contains 3 primitive int values" - what is the actual type of these objects? `Integer` it obviously can't be, as an `Integer` contains a single `int` value only. Is it a `List<Integer>` ?

Comment: The C code looks wrong since you don't declare a, b and c before the while. Also you don't increment P… In Java the code would look pretty much the same, using an Iterator<int[]> as P. However you could use a foreach loop instead.

Comment: ya peter sir it is a LinkedHashSet<List<Integer>> where each list contains 3 int values.actually i have converted array[n][3] into LinkedHashSet for removing duplicates and revert back i want it to convert into 2D int array.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement 3 different Lists . The most easy way to this is just to write a class that overrides  `java.util.AbstractList<E>` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html and selects an element from your 3-element list.

This is your solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DemuxList extends java.util.AbstractList<Integer>{

    ArrayList<Integer[]> listToDemux;
    int listIndex;

    DemuxList(ArrayList<Integer[]> listToDemux, int listIndex) {
        this.listToDemux = listToDemux;
        this.listIndex = listIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index)
    {
        Integer[] el = listToDemux.get(index);
        if (el != null) {
            return el[listIndex];
        } else {
            return null;
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return listToDemux.size();
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> fullList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
DemuxList l0 = new DemuxList(fullList, 0);
DemuxList l1 = new DemuxList(fullList, 1);
DemuxList l2 = new DemuxList(fullList, 2);
```

Comment: I see you added details about list types: `LinkedHashSet<Integer> [size<N><3>]`, when I was writing the code above. You need to little alter my code to your List type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the code is as follows.Given

```
LinkedHashSet<Set<Integer>> r;
i=0
for(<Set<Integer>> set:r)
    ar[i++]=s.toArray(new Integer[3]);
```

Where ar is a 2D array of size `[r.length][3]` because inner set in r having size 3.